# annotation_logticks outside of the plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce an example of annotation_logticks  {ggplot2}:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(scales)
a <- ggplot(Animals, aes(x = body, y = brain)) + geom_point() +
 scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
               labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
 scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
               labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
 theme_bw()

a + annotation_logticks()
```

But the ticks of the graphic output are out of the plot area

[image]

Any idea of how I can get a solution of this problem?

The sessionInfo() information is the following:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggtern_1.0.6.0         scales_0.3.0           MASS_7.3-44           
 [4] colorspace_1.2-6       data.table_1.9.6       reshape2_1.4.1        
 [7] car_2.1-0              dplyr_0.4.3.9000       xtable_1.7-4          
[10] Hmisc_3.16-0           Formula_1.2-1          survival_2.38-3       
[13] lattice_0.20-33        Rcpp_0.12.1            gridExtra_2.0.0       
[16] micromap_1.9.2         RColorBrewer_1.1-2     maps_2.3-11           
[19] raster_2.4-20          spatstat_1.42-2        spdep_0.5-88          
[22] Matrix_1.2-2           maptools_0.8-36        rgdal_1.0-7           
[25] sp_1.2-0               rgeos_0.3-12           gtable_0.1.2          
[28] FactoMineR_1.31.3      RCurl_1.95-4.7         bitops_1.0-6          
[31] bit64_0.9-5            bit_1.1-12             minpack.lm_1.1-9      
[34] xlsx_0.5.7             xlsxjars_0.6.1         rJava_0.9-7           
[37] stringr_1.0.0          prettyR_2.1-1          ggthemes_2.2.1        
[40] ggplot2_1.0.1          directlabels_2013.6.15 quadprog_1.5-5        
[43] plyr_1.8.3            

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1       latticeExtra_0.6-26  LearnBayes_2.15      quantreg_5.19       
 [5] chron_2.3-47         digest_0.6.8         polyclip_1.3-2       minqa_1.2.4         
 [9] SparseM_1.7          tensor_1.5           lme4_1.1-9           MatrixModels_0.4-1  
[13] mgcv_1.8-7           nnet_7.3-11          pbkrtest_0.4-2       proto_0.3-10        
[17] magrittr_1.5         deldir_0.1-9         nlme_3.1-122         foreign_0.8-66      
[21] tools_3.2.2          munsell_0.4.2        cluster_2.0.3        flashClust_1.01-2   
[25] nloptr_1.0.4         goftest_1.0-3        leaps_2.9            boot_1.3-17         
[29] abind_1.4-3          DBI_0.3.1            R6_2.1.1             stringi_0.5-5       
[33] parallel_3.2.2       rpart_4.1-10         acepack_1.3-3.3      scatterplot3d_0.3-36
[37] coda_0.17-1
```

I ran the code without loading ggtern library and the problem dissapeared. But I have to do some other graphics with ggtern and I don`t want to start another session

Comment: Where does Animails come from?

Comment: Is a dataset of MASS library

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem (had logticks inside the plotting area). You can post a link to the image you're creating, I or someone else can add it to your post as it seems relevant to the problem.

Comment: Can you add the code used to save your image?

Comment: I copied it from the Rstudio window

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem, plot looks fine, using R 3.2.2. Please add `sessionInfo()` to your post. What do you get when saved as jpeg: `ggsave("temp.jpeg",a)` ?

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I added sessionInfo(), I ran the code without loading ggtern library and the problem dissapeared. But I have to do some other graphics with ggtern and I don`t want to start another session

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have changed from the default settings for the screen device? Does this happen if you print to a file graphics device?

Comment: I saved with ggsave but the result was the same

Comment: presumably ggtern redefines a function that turns clipping off for the plot panel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution even in case ggtern is loaded:

```
library(ggtern)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(scales)
a <- ggplot(Animals, aes(x = body, y = brain)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  theme_bw() + annotation_logticks()  


library(grid)
grid.draw(ggplotGrob(a))
```

In case I don´t need ggtern the solution obviously is running the code without loading ggtern library.

[image]